Looking for some advice for my future patio
I'm looking to build a patio in this area where there is currently crushed stone. These were already there when I purchased the house. My question is, can I just compact this and build a patio on top or should I remove the crushed stones completely? It's about 2-3 inches worth of crushed stones. There is weed growing on top now but it does look like there is a weed barrier under.  



Is the pad going to be level with the pad behind it, or do you want a step down?

Can you? Sure! Should you? Probably not if you want to be confident in the new patio lasting a long time. You haven't a clue what's really under there, so you don't have a clue how long the new slab/pavers will last.

If you're going to buy pavers from a specialty stone/yard store, bring your pictures in and ask the people there for their advice.

I think the problem you have is the kind of gravel/stone that is used is not really the kind that compacts to form a solid base for a concrete pad.
I think the ideal setup would be to remove the material, put in crushed gravel (grain to 3/8" in size), compact, frame up, and pour the slab.

Agree—what the OP has isn't crushed stone, it's just gravel.  Looks like #57.

Thank you, I will remove the gravel and place it in my garden area and then follow the usual steps for the patio.
